# Parametrical Lyapunov's function for verification of the node's stability.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

**Problem statement**

I have been solving the sample variant of the control work on differential equations, which I will be having soon, when stumbled upon the following problem, which I find quite interesting, but challenging as well.
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\; \dot{x} &=&-2y-x^3, \\ 
\; \dot{y} &=&x-y^3. \\
\end{matrix}\right. \tag{1}$$
Given the system of nonlinear ODEs $(1)$, I have to explore the stability of the equilibrium node $(0, 0)$, by using Lyapunov's function of the following form: $\mathbb{V}(x,y) = ax^2 + by^2,$ for some constants $a, b$.

**My attempt**

As we know, in order to verify the node's stability, we have to find the derivative of $\mathbb{V}$ over $t$, if the derivative is greater than zero, then the equilibrium is unstable, else stable.

$$\dot{\mathbb{V}} = \frac{\partial \mathbb{V}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \mathbb{x}}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \mathbb{V}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial \mathbb{y}}{\partial t} = 2ax(-2y-x^3) + 2by(x-y^3) = -2a(2xy +x^4) + 2b(xy-y^4).$$

And there is the point, where I don't actually know, what exactly to do. First, I have tried to consider several cases for $a$ and $b$ ($a=b=0$; $a \gt b \gt 0$, $a=b\gt 0$, etc.), but then I realized, that if I am to do this separately, I will have to consider quite a lot of cases, even for $x$ and $y$, as it is not that clear overall, whether $\dot{\mathbb{V}}$ is less or greater than zero.

I want to know, by that point, whether there is a more simple method to understand, whether the node is stable or not. Also, I want to clarify, maybe I get the task incorrectly, and I just have to chose some $a, b$ by myself in order to verify the stability of the node?

Anyways, I would appreciate any help of yours!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Moo, I guess, actually, $\forall a,b > 0: \dot{\mathbb{V}} \leqslant 0.$ We may linearize $\hat{f} = 2b(xy - y^4)$ around zero, and hence $\mathcal{Lin}[\hat{f}] = \hat{f}(0,0) +x\hat{f}^{'}_{x}(0,0) + y\hat{f}^{'}_{y}(0,0) = 0.$ Now, $\hat{\mathbb{V}} \sim 0 - 2a(2xy+x^4).$ Hence for any positive choice of $a$ and $b$, the equilibrium node would be verified as stable. But what about other values of $a,b$? Should I consider them or not?

Comment: You should choose $a$ and $b$ such that the sign-indefinite term $xy$ is canceled, and only sign-definite terms $x^4$ and $y^4$ left. Start with setting $a=1$ and find $b$.